# How to deal with crates exporting symbols with identical names

Tags: rust, linker-errors, rust-crates, lnk2005, name-clash

I'd like to use both [`just-argon2`](https://crates.io/crates/just-argon2) and [`sodiumoxide`](https://crates.io/crates/sodiumoxide) which are bindings to [Argon2](https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-winner-argon2/) and [libsodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium) respectively. The first I will use for password hashing, the second for encryption and more.

However, because libsodium itself [also includes the Argon2 code](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/tree/fe1d6d1/src/libsodium/crypto_pwhash/argon2), I get the following linker error when building:

```
error: linking with `link.exe` failed: exit code: 1169
  |
  = note: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Preview\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30132\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\link.exe" "/NOLOGO" "/NXCOMPAT" "/LIBPATH:<omitted>\\rust-ms\\tools\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib" "<omitted>\\target\\debug\\deps\\sw_password_vault.sw_password_vault.cvsxie8m-cgu.0.rcgu.o" "<omitted>\\target\\debug\\deps\\sw_password_vault.sw_password_vault.cvsxie8m-cgu.1.rcgu.o" "<omitted>\\target\\debug\\deps\\sw_password_vault.sw_password_vault.cvsxie8m-cgu.10.rcgu.o" "<omitted>\\target\\debug\\deps\\sw_password_vault.sw_password_vault.cvsxie8m-cgu.11.rcgu.o" "<omitted>\\target\\debug\\deps\\sw_password_vault.sw_password_vault.cvsxie8m-cgu.12.rcgu.o" "<omitted>\\target\\debug\\deps\\sw_password_vault.sw_password_vault.cvsxie8m-cgu.13.rcgu.o" "<omitted>\\target\\debug\\deps\\sw_password_vault.sw_password_vault.cvsxie8m-cgu.14.rcgu.o" "<omitted>\\target\\debug\\deps\\sw_password_vault.sw_password_vault.cvsxie8m-cgu.15.rcgu.o" "<omitted>\\target\\debug\\deps\\sw_password_vault.sw_password_vault.cvsxie8m-cgu.2.rcgu.o" "<omitted>\\target\\debug\\deps\\sw_password_vault.sw_password_vault.cvsxie8m-cgu.3.rcgu.o" "<omitted>\\target\\debug\\deps\\sw_password_vault.sw_password_vault.cvsxie8m-cgu.4.rcgu.o" "<omitted>\\target\\debug\\deps\\sw_password_vault.sw_password_vault.cvsxie8m-cgu.5.rcgu.o" "<omitted>\\target\\debug\\deps\\sw_password_vault.sw_password_vault.cvsxie8m-cgu.6.rcgu.o" "<omitted>\\target\\debug\\deps\\sw_password_vault.sw_password_vault.cvsxie8m-cgu.7.rcgu.o" "<omitted>\\target\\debug\\deps\\sw_password_vault.sw_password_vault.cvsxie8m-cgu.8.rcgu.o" "<omitted>\\target\\debug\\deps\\sw_password_vault.sw_password_vault.cvsxie8m-cgu.9.rcgu.o" "/OUT:<omitted>\\target\\debug\\deps\\sw_password_vault.exe" "<omitted>\\target\\debug\\deps\\sw_password_vault.2501tt6qpnxmq6dq.rcgu.o" "/OPT:REF,NOICF" "/DEBUG" "/NATVIS:<omitted>\\rust-ms\\tools\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\intrinsic.natvis" "/NATVIS:<omitted>\\rust-ms\\tools\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\liballoc.natvis" "/NATVIS:<omitted>\\rust-ms\\tools\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\libcore.natvis" "/NATVIS:<omitted>\\rust-ms\\tools\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\libstd.natvis" "/LIBPATH:<omitted>\\target\\debug\\deps" "/LIBPATH:<omitted>\\target\\debug\\build\\just-argon2-fba8d38863f06c3e\\out" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\Steven\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\libsodium-sys-0.2.7\\msvc/x64/Debug/v142/" "/LIBPATH:<omitted>\\rust-ms\\tools\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib" "<omitted>\\target\\debug\\deps\\libargon2-47416e342f12fc80.rlib" "<omitted>\\target\\debug\\deps\\libbitflags-033856bffcb41e1a.rlib" "<omitted>\\target\\debug\\deps\\libsodiumoxide-ae3f70995957a7e5.rlib" "<omitted>\\target\\debug\\deps\\libserde-02c238cdfdb411bb.rlib" "<omitted>\\target\\debug\\deps\\libed25519-a72dcd735d2405a2.rlib" "<omitted>\\target\\debug\\deps\\libsignature-cb8ca284112f3bdb.rlib" "<omitted>\\target\\debug\\deps\\liblibsodium_sys-90db65a5d41df800.rlib" "<omitted>\\target\\debug\\deps\\liblibc-db8e81727092f722.rlib" "<omitted>\\rust-ms\\tools\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libstd-7d8f1d3120dc2b31.rlib" "<omitted>\\lib\\libpanic_unwind-00b4871c13b6f72d.rlib" "<omitted>\\lib\\libstd_detect-38300272c9518b1b.rlib" "<omitted>\\lib\\librustc_demangle-008ea074760d3d54.rlib" "<omitted>\\lib\\libhashbrown-5d102da67e495133.rlib" "<omitted>\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_alloc-108ed3dcf248b873.rlib" "<omitted>\\lib\\libunwind-bc9246c93f49e49a.rlib" "<omitted>\\lib\\libcfg_if-7ca234fdcd728c26.rlib" "<omitted>\\lib\\liblibc-e328514fb4ed0383.rlib" "<omitted>\\lib\\liballoc-5d0a4c6a1ffa6373.rlib" "<omitted>\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_core-d379e9227cab087f.rlib" "<omitted>\\lib\\libcore-825774e96423c2c5.rlib" "<omitted>\\lib\\libcompiler_builtins-d5d1908505fa83bc.rlib" "advapi32.lib" "ws2_32.lib" "userenv.lib" "msvcrt.lib"
  = note: liblibsodium_sys-90db65a5d41df800.rlib(blake2b-ref.obj) : error LNK2005: blake2b_init already defined in libargon2-47416e342f12fc80.rlib(blake2b.o)
          liblibsodium_sys-90db65a5d41df800.rlib(blake2b-ref.obj) : error LNK2005: blake2b_init_key already defined in libargon2-47416e342f12fc80.rlib(blake2b.o)
          liblibsodium_sys-90db65a5d41df800.rlib(blake2b-ref.obj) : error LNK2005: blake2b_init_param already defined in libargon2-47416e342f12fc80.rlib(blake2b.o)
          liblibsodium_sys-90db65a5d41df800.rlib(blake2b-ref.obj) : error LNK2005: blake2b_update already defined in libargon2-47416e342f12fc80.rlib(blake2b.o)
          liblibsodium_sys-90db65a5d41df800.rlib(blake2b-ref.obj) : error LNK2005: blake2b_final already defined in libargon2-47416e342f12fc80.rlib(blake2b.o)
          liblibsodium_sys-90db65a5d41df800.rlib(blake2b-ref.obj) : error LNK2005: blake2b already defined in libargon2-47416e342f12fc80.rlib(blake2b.o)
             Creating library C:\dev\Rust\SWPasswordVault\target\debug\deps\sw_password_vault.lib and object C:\dev\Rust\SWPasswordVault\target\debug\deps\sw_password_vault.exp
          LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
          C:\dev\Rust\SWPasswordVault\target\debug\deps\sw_password_vault.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

Both libraries export the same `blake2b_*` symbols, which are used by the Argon2 implementations, so the names clash.

Now you may be wondering: why not just use the libsodium `pwhash` API, which uses Argon2 internally (hence the linker error)? Because I want to use parallel Argon2, which is not exposed by libsodium, as it [hardcodes the degree of parallelism to 1](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/blob/fe1d6d1/src/libsodium/crypto_pwhash/argon2/pwhash_argon2id.c#L169).

Apparently, the `blake2b_*` symbols *are* [marked](https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-winner-argon2/blob/f57e61e/src/blake2/blake2.h#L70) as `ARGON2_LOCAL`, so they are [not exported](https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-winner-argon2/blob/f57e61e/include/argon2.h#L35), but I guess that this does not matter since they still exist for the linker.

One solution could be to use a pure Rust implementation of Argon2 such as [`rust-argon2`](https://crates.io/crates/rust-argon2), but I tested that one and unfortunately it is *a lot* slower.

How can I still use both libraries together? <s>Do I have to make a separate library crate using just `just-argon2` and export the functions provided by the `just-argon2` crate or something like that, or would that not work / is there a better way?</s> EDIT: this does not work.

Minimum non-compiling program:

```rs
use sodiumoxide;
use argon2;

fn main() { sodiumoxide::init(); }
```

While composing this program I noticed that when I swap the `use` statements it compiles fine, but it crashes at runtime:

```rs
use argon2;
use sodiumoxide;

fn main() {
    sodiumoxide::init().expect("Could not init libsodium");

    let password = "pass";

    let salt = sodiumoxide::crypto::pwhash::gen_salt().0;
    let mut key_bytes = [0u8; 32];

    // INSECURE cost parameters
    argon2::id_hash_raw(1, 1 << 10 /*1 MiB*/, 1,
                        Some(password.as_bytes()), Some(&salt), &mut key_bytes)
        .unwrap_or_else(|err| panic!("Error hashing: {:?}", err));
}
```

This crashes with a [`STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/596a1078-e883-4972-9bbc-49e60bebca55) Windows exception (`__fastfail(FAST_FAIL_STACK_COOKIE_CHECK_FAILURE)`), while it works fine when not using any sodiumoxide functions (and an all-zero salt, for example). Apparently the different exports clash or something?

By the way: I'm very new to Rust so it's safe to say I don't know all the ins and outs of it.

Comment: shot in the dark... have you tried configuring another linker? `[target.x86_64-pc-windows-msvc]
linker = "rust-lld"`

Comment: @Todd Thanks for your comment. Took me a minute to figure out I have to place this in `.cargo/config.toml` and not `Cargo.toml`. Unfortunately, it does not fix the issue. The error now becomes:
`linking with rust-lld failed: "rust-lld" "-flavor" "link" ... rust-lld: error: duplicate symbol: blake2b_init > defined at ...\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-...\just-argon2-1.2.0\phc-winner-argon2\src\blake2\blake2b.c:91 > libargon2-....rlib(blake2b.o) > defined at liblibsodium_sys-....rlib(blake2b-ref.obj)`
This linker also fails at compiletime for the swapped `use` statements, contrary to link.exe